# How to find the highest subject?

Tags: python

I have to print the highest of subject for each child for example xyz(child's name) Highest in abc(The subject in which he got highest) are qrs(The highest mark).
I made the following program:

```
subjects = ["Maths","English","Science"]
names = ["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtuba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"]
scores = [[10,8,7],[8,8,6],[7,5,4],[4,0,2],[3,9,4],[7,8,3],[8,7,5],[9,5,7],[8,7,9]]
a=0
while a<len(names):
    highest=scores[a][0]
    i=0
    while i<=2:
        if scores[a][i]>highest:
            highest=scores[a][i]
        i=i+1

    print(names[a]+"'s Highest in",highest)
    a=a+1
```

The output is:

```
Talha's Highest: 10
Fazeel's Highest: 8
Usayd's Highest: 7
Mujtuba's Highest: 4
Sufyan's Highest: 9
Aukasha's Highest: 8
Moiz's Highest: 8
Mohid's Highest: 9
Wasil's Highest: 9
```

The problem is it's not teeling the subject in which the students get the highest.Please tell me what to add in this code to do so...

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix of your code to include the subject:

```
subjects = ["Maths","English","Science"]
names = ["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtuba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"]
scores = [[10,8,7],[8,8,6],[7,5,4],[4,0,2],[3,9,4],[7,8,3],[8,7,5],[9,5,7],[8,7,9]]
a=0
while a<len(names):
    highest=scores[a][0]
    subject=subjects[0]
    i=0
    while i<=2:
        if scores[a][i]>highest:
            highest=scores[a][i]
            subject=subjects[i]
        i=i+1

    print(names[a]+"'s Highest in", subject,highest)
    a=a+1
```

However, your code isn't very pythonic and can be written simpler:

```
for i, student in enumerate(names):
    score, subject = max(zip( scores[i], subjects))
    print(f"{student}'s best subject is {subject} with a score of {score}")
```

Which does the same thing.

Comment: thank you for your help btw it would be print(names[a]+"'s Highest in",subject, highest)